# Read in game stats table from MLB website into Beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape/read in the Game Stats table from an MLB player website (https://www.mlb.com/player/charlie-morton-450203?stats=gamelogs-r-pitching-mlb&year=2019). I cannot seem to find/capture the class name. I can see the class name when I "inspect the HTML" in chrome, but beautiful soup does not seem to findit.

Is there some workaround/trick to getting this in correctly?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page = requests.get('https://www.mlb.com/player/charlie-morton-450203?stats=gamelogs-r-pitching-mlb&year=2019')

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")
body = soup.find('body')

table = body.findAll('div', {'class':'gamelogs-table'})
print(table)
```

Comment: version 4 of BeautifulSoup uses find_all() not findAll()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data is loaded through AJAX. For the correct source of data you need to find URL through e.g. developer console in Firefox. This script prints the JSON data of player `450203`:

```
import requests
import json

url = 'https://statsapi.mlb.com/api/v1/people/450203/stats?stats=gameLog'
data = requests.get(url).json()

print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to retrieve the data, I would suggest you look for existing APIs like [this](https://github.com/toddrob99/MLB-StatsAPI) before attempting to scrape the website. Scrapers are susceptible to website layout changes.

[This](https://www.reddit.com/r/mlbdata/) is a reddit forum that you may be interested in.